# Hourly historical data in Google Trends?

Tags: data-request

It was possible to collect any data on google trends hour by hour in the past.
However, Google changed the search engine, and nowadays, we can only get hourly data at the platform since a week ago.
Some solutions (e.g., PyTrends) are not working correctly.
Is there any way to get historical hourly data at Google Trends that works in 2022?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm following this question since `pytrends` is not a reliable tool.